# How to add click event to Toast notification from notification hub?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I need to add onclick action to Toast notification coming from notification hub .

I'm  developing a windows 8.1 universal app ,I need to navigate the user to another page when he click the toast

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the toast notifications using the following code snippet:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
  string launchString = args.Arguments;

  ....
}
```

You have to set **launch** parameters while creating toasts like this:

```
var navigationString = ""#/MainPage.xaml?param1=12345";
var toastElement = ((XmlElement)toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast"));
toastElement.SetAttribute("launch", navigationString);
```

More details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868212.aspx
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/59b9d6/toast-notification-for-wp-8-1/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from the `launch` attribute which was specified in the toast XML in the `OnLaunched` method in `App` class. Every time a user clicks a notification in the notification hub this method will be called because you are launching the app via a toast notification.

The actual value will be in `args.Arguments`.